# How I could fetch data per API?

Tags: python, rest

I would like to ask, what I am doing wrong in code that I am not getting all data from website API?
For example, in my JSON is missing data 2022-01-03 8:00 Vikings Exchange.
Website: https://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/news/companynews.

```
import requests
import json
import time
import csv
import pandas
 
start=250
 
with open('C:/Users/apskaita3/Desktop/number2.txt', "r") as f:

    start= f.readlines()
 
start=int(start[0])
 
start=start + 70


results = {"item": {}}

# Todo load json
for i in range(0,9800): #<----- Just change range here to increase number of requests
    URL = f"https://api.news.eu.nasdaq.com/news/query.action?type=handleResponse&showAttachments=true&showCnsSpecific=true&showCompany=true&countResults=false&freeText=&company=&market=Main%20Market%2C+Helsinki&cnscategory=&fromDate=&toDate=&globalGroup=exchangeNotice&globalName=NordicMainMarkets&displayLanguage=en&language=en&timeZone=CET&dateMask=yyyy-MM-dd+HH%3Amm%3Ass&limit=19&start={i}&dir=ASC"
    r = requests.get(url = URL)
    #time.sleep(1)
    res = r.text.replace("handleResponse(", "")
    #print(res)
    #print(f'r is {r}')
    res_json = json.loads(res)
    #print(res_json)
    data = res_json
    a=i+1
    #print(data)
    print("Doing: " + str(i + 1) + "th")
    #data = r.json()
    
    downloaded_entries = data["results"]["item"]
    new_entries = [d for d in downloaded_entries if d["headline"] not in results["item"]]
    start=str(start)
    
    for entry in new_entries:
        if entry["market"] == 'Main Market, Helsinki' and entry["published"]>="2021-10-20 06:30:00":
            headline = entry["headline"].strip()
            published = entry["published"]
            market=entry["market"]
            market="Main Market, Helsinki"
            results["item"][headline] = {"company": entry["company"], "messageUrl": entry["messageUrl"], "published": entry["published"], "headline": headline}
            print(entry['market'])
            #time.sleep(5)
            print(f"Market: {market}/nDate: {published}/n")
            #print( results["item"][headline] )
            #print(results)
            #print(json.dumps({"item": list(results["item"].values())}, indent = 4))
            
with open("C:/Users/apskaita3/Finansų analizės ir valdymo sprendimai, UAB/Rokas Toomsalu - Power BI analitika/Integracijos/1_Public comapnies analytics/Databasesets/Others/market_news_helsinki.json", "w") as outfile:    
    json_object = json.dumps({"item": list(results["item"].values())}, indent = 4)
    outfile.write(json_object)
    #print(json_object)
with open("C:/Users/apskaita3/Desktop/number2.txt", "w") as outfile1:    
    outfile1.write(start)  # type: ignore
```

I expecting to get all data from website, Helsinki market. I have tried to fetch data, I am getting a big part of data but not all.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @reproducile example - Commnutyi. How its should look like?